# GET a package from NuGetV3 API

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I'm interested in writing a client library for the NuGet v3 API in a non-.NET language.

What are the requests required to get a package, and what does the response looks like?

i.e.

GET {package-versions}
GET {package-version}

Can you also link to the official documentation that covers this scenario?

Comment: Searching for off-site links is obviously off-topic, but when you find info consider updating tag's wiki (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/nuget/info )

Comment: It is very likely that your only hope is the C# code, https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/tree/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3

Comment: Polite request for documentation https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4062

Comment: https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/api/nuget-api-v3

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview) is the official NuGet V3 API documentation. The API is composed of multiple protocols, including:

1. The [PackageBaseAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/package-base-address-resource) - The store that contains the actual packages and their manifest files (the `nuspec`).
2. The [Service Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/service-index) - used by the client to discover the NuGet services
3. The [Search Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/search-query-service-resource) - used by clients to search for NuGet packages
4. The [Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/registration-base-url-resource) - A json-LD based structure that stores the packages' metadata. This includes packages' content, dependencies, descriptions, etc...

For example, say you wanted to download the package "Newtonsoft.
Json":

1. Get the service index: `GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

The response contains the address of the PackageBaseAddress (aka, incorrectly as the flat container, as it is hierarchical and not flat :) ):

```
{
  "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/",
  "@type": "PackageBaseAddress/3.0.0",
  "comment": "Base URL of Azure storage where NuGet package registration info for DNX is stored, in the format https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/{id-lower}/{version-lower}.{version-lower}.nupkg"
},
```

2. Use the uri provided by the @id as a base uri to list the versions of the desired package: `GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json`, note that this uri is subject to change and is not part of the API
3. Use the same base uri to download a package: `GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/6.0.4/newtonsoft.json.6.0.4.nupkg`

You may also want to look at the [NuGet client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk). The client's source code is
[here](https://github.com/nuget/nuget.client); you'll want to start from the [NuGet.CommandLine project](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/tree/dev/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.CommandLine) and walk your way down the stack.

Comment: Awesome, very informative. Thanks for your response!